# Could one call eigenstates of $ \hat{a} = \hat{x} + i\hat{p}$ coherent states for other potentials than the harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-states, coherent-states

Let's say I look at the quantum system of a particle in one dimension, subject to any other potential than the one of the harmonic oscillator, and I define $\hat{a}$ as stated above. I would find the same eigenstates of $\hat{a}$ (as in the case of the harmonic oscillator), I could displace them in the same fashion with the displacement operator, their wigner function would look the same, they would also minimize uncertainty of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ ...

In short, they would resemble the known coherent states in almost any aspect:
The only thing that would be different with a different hamiltonian would be that they won't necessarily remain a coherent state under time evolution - probably they would disperse, or something else happens, depending on the potential.

Would one call this state still a coherent state?

Comment: Coherent states are simply defined as the eigenstates of $\hat{a}$, with no reference to the Hamiltonian. In general it would not be an eigenstate of Hamiltonian if the potential is not the parabolic one.

Comment: @MengCheng The coherent states are not *eigenstates* of $H$ even for a harmonic oscillator.  However, they are useful.

Comment: @MengCheng then why does any atempted generalization of coherent states usually involve some lie-group? (See for example https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286493/generalized-coherent-states-in-arbitrary-potential)